# How to extract the frequency from a DataFrame TimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I want the frequency in seconds as an int.

```
df.index.freq
```

returns something like

```
<5 * seconds>
```

I can do string parsing on str() of this, but it feels silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.index.freq.delta.value / 10**9
```

The underlying value is stored in nanoseconds, so you will have to apply a conversion factor using this method.

Alternatively, you can get it directly like this:

```
df.index.freq.delta.seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.delta.seconds` accessor:

```
In [48]: df.index.freq.delta.seconds
Out[48]: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

If frequency is unknown you need parse `int` form `string` created by [`DatetimeIndex.freqstr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.freqstr.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=3, freq='5S'))
print (df.index.freqstr)
5S

import re

i = int(re.search(r'\d+', df.index.freqstr).group())
print (i)
5
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=3, freq='10MS'))
print (df.index.freqstr)
10MS

i = int(re.search(r'\d+', df.index.freqstr).group())
print (i)
10
```

And if frequency is clear, use @MaxU solution.